# Use MOSFET as switch enabled by Arduino output

Tags: arduino

I have an input from a source at 5V with a maximum current of I believe 2A. I want to drive an output also at 5V but only at certain times. The output should be capable of supplying up to 1A at 5V. The arduino has other sensors and when certain values on these sensors are reached the input source should be passed to output. Initially I was driving the output straight from the digital HIGH output pin of the arduino however that can only handle very small currents.

I realise I need a logic-level MOSFET switch which will be controlled by the arduino HIGH output digital pin. Now, the question is there are so many available I don't know which to choose. Ideally I want something small that's easy to solder onto a custom PCB. Here are the options:

STP55NF06L
STB55NF06LT4 (out of stock)
FQP30N06L
RFP30N06LE (out of stock)
FDC6401N

I'm leaning towards the FDC6401N but I just want to be sure that this will work. Also by the way the same 5V from the source will be powering the arduino. The 5V on both inputs and outputs are coming from USB interfaces(not from a computer)
I would prefer a SMD but all the SMDs I've seen are dual MOSFETs which seems like a waste to me.

Comment: Something you might consider are USB downstream power switch chips, for example the RT9742.  These are typically NFETs, but with the necessary circuitry to make them function as high side switches; some also have current limit capability which might be useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a dual P+N channel, such as a [DMC2038LVT](https://www.diodes.com/assets/Datasheets/DMC2038LVT.pdf).

[image]

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fzBALF.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

If your load is heavily capacitive you may have to deliberately slow the turn-on.

Comment: Great! This seems to be cheapest of them all as well. Just to clarify, I would only be using the P channel MOSFET inside this package right. And in terms of wiring, G2 would be the "enable" active high signal from the arduino digital pin output, D2 would be the input USB 5V and S2 would be the output USB Voltage line which will end up being 5V with G2 is high and 0V when G2 is low.

Comment: You can use the single P-channel if your Vdd for the MCU is 5V. It's active low. If you use the high-side switch as shown above, the input is active high and you can have Vdd less than 5V (eg. 3.3V).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the [FDC6401N](http://www.mouser.com/ds/2/149/FDC6401N-1007133.pdf) would work perfectly for 1 Amp IDS when VGS is >4.5V (aka the 5V output). At 54 cents USD per 1 unit, you should just get a bunch and not worry about not using the second mosfet. They are dirt cheap for hobby use.

Comment: No, this probably won't work.  The application sounds envisioned to use high side switching, and as AnalogKid points out, these are NFETs.  So some rethinking would be necessary to use this.

Comment: Nothing in the question suggest that

Comment: "I want to drive an output also at 5V" "The 5V on both inputs and outputs are coming from USB interfaces".  It's possible low side switching would work, but that's highly unusual for USB and potentially problematic if the data lines are used.

Comment: I'll provide some more clarifications. The USB port on the PCB I'm designing will provide power to the ATMega328P-PU(arduino right now for prototyping) at 5V. Depending on what other sensor data the Arduino receives, I would like to either pass through that 5V from the input USB to the output USB which should also be 5V or block it - A switch. The output USB will be used to power some other device. My apologies if my question was not clear. I'm not entirely sure what low-side and high side switching is. Would something like this work - FQP27P06 or this FQB27P06TM

Answer (score 0):

The parts you list are n-channel MOSFETs.  For such a part to be a saturated switch with 5 V in and out, the gate must be several volts above the source.  For a logic level part in a 5 V circuit, that means that the gate is 8-10 V above GND.  Assuming you do not have +10 V or +12 V available for a gate driver circuit, there are ways around this.

One is to use a floating gate driver part.  This is an IC with built-in capacitors and a charge pump to make an output voltage that is high enough to drive an n-channel gate in your type of application.  A corollary to this is to build a charge pump gate driver circuit, which could be as simple as making the arduino control signal be a square wave and have it drive a couple of diodes and capacitors.

Another is to use a p-channel MOSFET or PNP power transistor, and drive the gate/base with a signal that goes low when you want the power output to be on.

Another is to use a photomos solid state relay.  This is a small part like an optocoupler, but the output is a pair of mosfets that can handle 1-2 A.  Working from memory, CP Clare invented them and that business now is part of IXYS.  LCA701/710/717.  Panasonic also makes them.  Note that the on-resistance will not be as low as a single power MOSFET, but maybe low enough for your application.

To help determine the best path, tell us how quickly the power will be turned on and off.

Comment: The switch will only operate at a maximum of like once every 5 minutes or so. How about something like theses - FQP27P06 or this FQB27P06TM

Comment: Certainly is beefy enough, but it is not a logic-level part.  The threshold voltage can be as high as 4 V.  According to the conduction curves it should be "on" enough for your application, but it will not be "hard saturated" so it's on resistance will vary with more temperature.  I'd qualify it before committing to production.

Comment: There seems to be so many chips that will be applicable in this case. The output USB will just be providing power for a small usb gadget, max of 1A probably draw. I'm not too concerned of being exact.

Comment: Agree, lotsa options.  Anything with an on resistance of 0.1 ohm or less should work.  The DMC part mentioned above is kinda cute.